# List users by using two custom meta fields with query in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, custom-fields

I am trying to create a user list, by filtering it with 3 user meta values.

Firstly I created a form with two select options that have the different possible values for the meta fields. Then I created a filtered query and used the values from the form, the first value (`$search`) works perfectly, but the second one doesn't work and I have no idea why.

If I substitute the second value in

```
'key' => 'distrito_profissao'
```

it will work perfectly.

```
'value' => 'Leiria'
```

I also don't understand why this value (`$search2`) doesn't stay saved when I submit it and the other one does.

```
add_shortcode('user_search_C','My_User_search_C');

function My_User_search_C() {

?>
 <?php
 $search=get_query_var( 'as' );
 $search2=get_query_var( 'bs' );


 // Array of stdClass objects.
 ?>

 <ul class="users_list">

 <form>     
    <label for="as" ></label>
    <select name="as"  id="as"  >
            <option value="" <?php selected( $search, "" ); ?> ></option>
            <option value="CAPDA"<?php selected( $search, "CAPDA" ); ?> >Crianças e adolescentes com perturbações do desenvolvimento e aprendizagem</option>
            <option value="CMPIP"<?php selected( $search, "CMPIP" ); ?> >Crianças em meio pré-escolar e/ou Intervenção Precoce</option>
            <option value="CACP"<?php selected( $search, "CACP" ); ?> >Crianças e adolescentes em contexto pedopsiquiátrico</option>
            <option value="MA" <?php selected( $search, "MA" ); ?> >Meio Aquático</option>
            <option value="SMAI"<?php selected( $search, "SMAI" ); ?> >Saúde mental do adulto e do idoso</option>
        </select><br/>



        <label for="bs"></label>
        <select name="bs" id="bs"  >
            <option value="" <?php selected( $search2, "" ); ?>></option>
            <option value="Beja" <?php selected( $search2, "Beja" ); ?> >Beja</option>
            <option value="Braga" <?php selected( $search2, "Braga" ); ?> >Braga</option>
            <option value="Bragança" <?php selected( $search2, "Bragança" ); ?> >Bragança</option>
            <option value="Castelo Branco" <?php selected( $search2, "Castelo Branco" ); ?> >Castelo Branco</option>
            <option value="Coimbra" <?php selected( $search2, "Coimbra" ); ?> >Coimbra</option>
            <option value="Évora" <?php selected( $search2, "Évora" ); ?> >Évora</option>
            <option value="Guarda" <?php selected( $search2, "Guarda" ); ?> >Guarda</option>
            <option value="Leiria" <?php selected( $search2, "Leiria" ); ?> >Leiria</option>
            <option value="Lisboa" <?php selected( $search2, "Lisboa" ); ?> >Lisboa</option>
            <option value="Portalegre" <?php selected( $search2, "Portalegre" ); ?> >Portalegre</option>
            <option value="Porto" <?php selected( $search2, "Porto" ); ?> >Porto</option>
            <option value="Santarém" <?php selected( $search2, "Santarém" ); ?> >Santarém</option>
            <option value="Setúbal" <?php selected( $search2, "Setúbal" ); ?> >Setúbal</option>
            <option value="Viana do Castelo" <?php selected( $search2, "Viana do Castelo" ); ?> >Viana do Castelo</option>
            <option value="Vila Real" <?php selected( $search2, "Vila Real" ); ?> >Vila Real</option>
            <option value="Viseu" <?php selected( $search2, "Viseu" ); ?> >Viseu</option>
        </select></br>

        <input type="submit" id="submit" />


  </form>

  <?php

 $blogusers = get_users( array('fields' => array( 'display_name'),array('meta_key' => $metakey,$metakey2),array('meta_value' => $search2,$search),'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'key' => 'list_prof',
        'value' => 'S',
        'compare' => '='
    ),
    array('relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'key' => 'distrito_profissao',
        'value' => $search2,
        'compare' => '='
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'area_profissao',
        'value' => $search,
        'compare' => '='
    )


)) )); 
 foreach ( $blogusers as $user ) {

echo '<li>' . esc_html( $user->display_name ) . '</li>';
}
 ?>
 </ul>

 <?php
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are both Query Vars defined? Here's how I define them:

```
function e3_add_query_vars($vars) {
    $vars[] = 'as';
    $vars[] = 'bs';
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'e3_add_query_vars' );
```

If you have a registered taxonomy, it automatically registers that query var making this unnecessary in some cases (I had some cases in my theme where I needed this and some where I didn't)

Comment: I just did but the result is the same, It still doesn't save the second  variable

Comment: Have you tried echoing the two variables to ensure that $search2 is empty?

Comment: That is exactly the point $serch2 is always empty and i don't know why because the code is exactly the same as $search ! And  $search gives the rigth echo.

Comment: I've updated my answer with another thought about defining the query vars